# Dependency not satisfiable : libqtmultimediakit1

Tags: lubuntu, dependencies, deb

Lubuntu 16.04

I was trying to install screencloud from a deb file, but I got that error. How do I resolve this?
[image]

Comment: That are the instructions for install in this program website? What Ubuntu release are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to include that, edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/06/force-install-screencloud-ubuntu-16-04).

1. `wget http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qtmobility/libqtmultimediakit1_1.2.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb`
2. `sudo dpkg -i libqtmultimediakit1_1.2.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb`
   3.`sudo apt-get install -f`
3. `sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/olav-st/xUbuntu_15.10/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/screencloud.list"`
4. `sudo apt-get update`
5. `wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:olav-st/xUbuntu_15.10/Release.key`
6. `sudo apt-key add - < Release.key`
7. `sudo apt-get install screencloud`

Comment: That installed screencloud, but I dont get a tray icon, nor do any of the shortcut keys work, I guess Ill just have to live without it for the time being. Accepted as best answer